# Setup aws route 53 for sedo parking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, nameservers

I have several domains registered with AWS Route53 and would like to offer them for sale on SEDO. To show they are parked with SEDO I need to redirect my traffic to SEDO. 
I have created the name servers in accordance to SEDO's support as:

NS1.SEDOPARKING.COM
NS2.SEDOPARKING.COM

in the record set for the domains.
I also waited a couple of days (it's now been two weeks) for the changes to set in. However, nothing has happened.

Does anyone know what else I need to change in the Route53 record sets for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

If your domain is registered with AWS, you should be making those changes in Route 53 --> Registered domains section. As an example, if you look at my screenshot, you would replace **nora.ns.cloudflare.com** and **wesley.ns.cloudflare.com** with **NS1.SEDOPARKING.COM** and **NS2.SEDOPARKING.COM**.

[image]

Comment: This is correct.  Additionally, in this situation there is no need for a Route 53 hosted zone at all.